# How to get text based user input using GLib

Tags: c, user-interface, user-input, stdin, glib

GLib/GIO offer some great ways to print messages, read files and do some other IO, but I couldn't find any way to simply get user input from stdin.

What is the recommended way to achive this?

Furthermore it would be nice to handle input asynchronously from the mainloop using some kind of GCallback. Is there a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why just not reading it with GIO from stdin? It's no easy task though, as you must check for the environment, and use GUnixInputStream and GWin32InputStream depending on that. I wonder why the GLib guys didn't think about this yet...